# Query post with meta_query where date is not in future

Tags: wp-query, post-meta, query-posts, sql

In my args I would like to **exclude** posts where the datum_event is **not in the future**. Currently it only displays posts with datum_event values that are in the past, but because older posts don't have any value for datum_event, the old posts don't get shown.

I know how to compare against a single value, but how do I compare against all future dates?

Basically: EXCLUDE posts with `datum_event` `compare` future.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'agenda',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'datum_event',
            'value'   => date('Ymd'),
            'compare' => '<='
        )
    ),
);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood you. You are saying you want to retrieve all posts which have the `dateum_event` value in the past AND also, at the same time, you want to retrieve posts where the `datum_event` value is blank (does not exist)? Is that it?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to type 'not' :-) I ment I want retrieve all posts which have the datum_event NOT in the future. @filipecsweb

Comment: And the answer below does not fit you?

Comment: Let me know if it does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try adding a second meta_query that would look for anything without the meta key:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'agenda',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => 'datum_event',
            'value'   => date('Ymd'),
            'compare' => '<='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'datum_event',
            'meta_compare' => 'NOT_EXISTS',
            'value' => 'placeholder'
        ),
    ),
);
```

Note that the value of placeholder is required to the make the not exists work - see https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

This is untested code but hopefully it helps!

Comment: How would you expand this functionality to order by normal post date if the post has no value for 'datum_event'? - I'd like to know this for a page with the same query but the sql on this page also includes two other posttypes that do not have the 'datum_event' field at all.

Comment: I believe you can just use the orderby param - https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

Comment: Would you be so kind te explain how @welcher? See my separate question here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/327318/orderby-meta-value-or-if-meta-value-doesnt-exist-post-date

Comment: The code above doesn't work. I have to remove the upper meta_query array so that the posts without data in datum_event are displayed..

Comment: @Ludo looks like your other question has been deleted. As to the code above not working, I did mention it was untested. I do believe the theory behind it is correct ( using the `relation` param with 2 query types ) but you may need to adjust some of the meta_query items.